# Is it possible to use a Spektrum DX5e as a normal joystick?

Tags: controllers

I have a Spektrum DX5e and a Phoenix RC Simulator. Phoenix contained a USB adapter that allows me to connect the DX5e to the PC. I'm running Windows 7.

Is it now possible to use the Spektrum DX5e as a normal joystick for other games?

Comment: Hm, not sure if Windows 7 tag is necessary but gonna wait for a 2nd opinion. It would be better if you just mentioned the OS in your question.

Comment: I did some searching, are you sure that you have the right connector into the controller some people says you have to have an adapter: http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102669&cp=&sr=1&kw=mono+adapter&origkw=mono+adapter&parentPage=search

Comment: I just have the connector/adapter that came with Phoenix RC. Pretty sure that's a proprietary connector.